# Heroku - Django: Had to change every mentioning of `myproject` into `app` to get my site working. How to best avoid this in the future?

Tags: python, django, heroku, importerror

I just ran my website made with Django1.3 for the first time on Heroku. I had to change every mentioning of `myproject` into `app`(such as `import myproject.core.views` into `import app.core.views` in `urls.py` ) in order to make my website run without an `importError`.

I figure either:

- I change the Heroku directory (`$ heroku run pwd` ouputs `/app`) `/app` into `/myproject`. How do I do this?
- Use a general prefix. How would I would I do this the best way?
- I should push my project from a directory lower?

**Update**

This is the file structure of my local and heroku directory: 
[gist.github.com/3361637](http://gist.github.com/3361637)

Here is an example of the changes I had to make in urls.py: 
[gist.github.com/3361686](http://gist.github.com/3361686)

The changes for the other files were exactly the same, just changing the name of my project

**Update2**

To mipadi:

Next to your proposed structure I changed my .git folder from this:

```
.
|-- myproject_django
    |-- core
        # etc.
    |-- manage.py
    |-- .git
    # etc
|-- requirements.txt
```

to this:

```
.
|-- myproject_django
    |-- core
        # etc.
    |-- manage.py
    # etc
|-- requirements.txt
|-- .git
```

and pushed the changes to heroku. But now the folders/files are mixed with the previous structure. I tried to delete these files using `heroku run rm file_name` but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should definitely use a specific prefix for your project.  There are a ton of possible situations where a generic module name could cause trouble.  Namespacing is important, because you never know who else might have named a module "app" or "myproject".

Comment: When I said general prefix, I meant using something like `os.path` so you can use a variable as a general prefix.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your situation, but I don't see why you would want a variable prefix unless you expect the name of your module to change frequently.

Comment: Because I want to be able to run my local version of it while not having to name it to `app`. I want to be able to push changes to heroku without having to rename each time.

Comment: And why not rename it to `something_descriptive` and run it that way both locally and on Heroku?  Configuration should differ between environments, not the structure of your project.

Comment: How do I configure that on Heroku? I think I'm missing something very simple here. How can I rename the heroku `app` directory name?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Procfile and/or WSGI script?  There's nothing in the Heroku deployment process that requires your app package to be named `app`.  I suspect it's just a configuration problem.

Comment: I don't have a procfile. I followed [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) and it didn't state I had to use a procfile to get it working. (at least not to the point where I am at deployment) I'm just using the django development server btw.

Comment: A procfile is for when you're ready to deploy a production version that isn't using the dev server.  In that case, it should just be running ./manage.py runserver on deployment.  I'd suggest renaming your project folder to something more descriptive.  I don't know why arbitrarily renaming `myproject` works for you unless you have `app` somewhere in your project structure.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, to get better answers on this question I'd suggest posting the actual traceback from your error as well as the file structure of your repository, for starters.

Comment: This is the file structure of my local and heroku directory: https://gist.github.com/3361637 .
Here is an example of the changes I had to make in urls.py: https://gist.github.com/3361686 .
The changes for the other files were exactly the same, just changing the name of my project to `app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Heroku's instructions (and every Django/Heroku project I've set up), the Django *project* should be at the top level, so, in your case, this:

```
.
|-- pykaboo_django
    |-- core
        # etc.
    |-- manage.py
    # etc
|-- requirements.txt
```

Then, you can just import by app name:

```
from core.models import *
```

Comment: This seems like the solution I was looking for. Could you check my second update of the original post?

Comment: @Bentley4, did you move your .git directory by hand?  I don't see how the original files would still be on heroku if you changed the app structure, committed, and re-pushed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should be referencing your module directly as `core` since it resides at the root of your project.  So, in `urls.py` you should be importing like:

```
import core.views
```

instead of `import app.core.views` or `import myproject.core.views`

Comment: You should be able to do that, anyway. The issue here is that Django adds the parent directory of the project to the PYTHONPATH; on his dev machine, the parent is "myproject", but on Heroku, the parent directory is "app".

Comment: this is what I do. reference from app level not project level: 
`ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'` instead of `ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'` for stuff outside an app. For stuff in an app: 
`from blog.models import BlogPost, Author` instead of `from myproject.blog.models import BlogPost, Author`. I can confirm that this works on heroku.

Comment: Yep, Francis, this mirrors my setup as well.

Comment: Dear Casey, thank you for taking so much time to help me. Your answer is certainly useful and works but mipadi's structure was what I was originally looking for. If I could accept two answers I would except yours as well, sorry.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted out.