# How to deal with heroku renaming my root-level app?

Tags: django, heroku

Heroku seems to prefer the apps deployed have a certain structure, mostly that the .git and manage.py is at root level and everything else is below that.

I have inherited a Django app I'm trying to deploy for testing purposes and I don't think I can restructure it so I was wondering if I have an alternative.

The structure I've inherited has most of the files in the root folder:

```
./foo: 
  __init__.py, 
  .git, 
  Procfile, 
  settings.py, 
  manage.py, 
  bar/
    models.py, etc
```

From within foo I can run `python manage.py shell` and in there `from foo.bar import models` works.

However, when I push this to Heroku, it puts the root in `/app`, so `foo` becomes `app` and `from foo.bar import models` no longer works.

Is there any magic settings that would allow me to indicate that `app` is really `foo` and allow me to continue without refactoring the app structure and/or all the imports?

*Similar question*: I think my question is similar to [Heroku - Django: Had to change every mentioning of `myproject` into `app` to get my site working. How to best avoid this in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972817/heroku-django-had-to-change-every-mentioning-of-myproject-into-app-to-get), except I'm asking if there's anything I can do without changing the site structure.

Comment: what is in your procfile?

Comment: Procfile `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a line to manage.py that modifies sys.path to make sure that `foo` is in your path:

```
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
if PROJECT_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)
```

Although as a side note its not really good django style to have your toplevel directory be a python module, precisely because it makes deployment more complicated (I'm not POSITIVE that the above will work on heroku).  I might recommend just changing your code to import from `bar` directly and removing `foo/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to delete `foo/__init__.py` and modify your import statements to import from `bar` instead of from `foo`, eg

```
from foo.bar.models import *
```

becomes

```
from bar.models import *
```

Alternatively you can use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). So if you wanted to import `bar.models` in `bar.views`, you'd do

```
from .models import *
```

The reason this is an issue is that Django 1.4 changed folder structure for newly created projects. Before 1.4 you'd have a similar structure like you described, minus `foo/__init__.py`. Heroku adapted Django 1.4's project structure, which is arguably better because it encapsulates the settings within the project and makes it more portable.